# How to get mp4 files from my PC to my iPad 2

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have some .m4v videos (I believe this is mp4 format?).  In iTunes (v10.5.0) on my PC (Windows 7 - 64 bit), I did a 'add file to library' and they appear under TV shows under library.

Then I did a sync with my iPad.  They do not seem to appear in my iPad (iPad 2, now running iOS 5).  The rest of the sync seems to go fine (i.e. recent songs are added to iPad, apps are all fine).  There is no error or warning message. Either I'm failing to see them in the iPad (I looked under TV shows and some other places, where should I look?), or they weren't really pushed to the iPad.

Perhaps the format is not supported or some other problem?  Like I said, no warning or error.  Finally, I should mention that in iTunes under "Dave's iPad", they appear under TV Shows.

How can I see my .mp4 files on the iPad?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the sync settings for your iPad are? Specifically the manually manage setting, and the settings under the TV Shows tab.

Comment: And also there is many sorts of MP4 videos. Perhaps the nitrate is too high, or it uses a codec incompatible with iOS. Could you give us more info about the video file?

Comment: CanuckSkier,I'm still getting use to iTunes.  I have all automatic settings (I believe). Where do I see the "manually mangage setting" and the TV Shows tab settings?  I've gone to Edit->Preferences.  Thats seems to be general.

Comment: Fred, I'm new to this but when I right click the file, I see that Type of File is MP4 Video,Video settings are: Frame Rate = 29 frames /second; data rate =1403 kbps; total bitrate 1529 kbps;frame width =640 ; frame height =480 Audio setings: bitrate = 125 kpbps;audio sample rate 44 khz.  I do not see any info about Codec.  I can see that it plays with no problems on my PC using iTunes Player.

Comment: @Fred Sorry, but "perhaps the nitrate is too high" made me laugh. :)

Answer (score 1):

The sordid state of app names for Audio / Video is kind of annoying in iOS' history.

- On the iPhone, before iOS 5, there was an iPod icon, which did audio and video.
- On the iPod touch, no matter the version, there have always been separate 'Music' and 'Video' icons.
- On the iPad, before iOS 5, there was an iPod icon, which only did audio, and there was a seperate Video icon for videos.

As of iOS 5, all devices now have separate "Music" and "Video" app icons. At least they're consistent now…

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, found it.  It was on the iPad all along.  Under "Videos".  [That is there is a "Videos" icon on iPad].  I don't recall this is where they appeared for some other material I transfer to iPad (pre-iOS 5), but perhaps I'm mistaken.    I was expecting it in iTunes icon on iPad. Note that in iTunes itself, it's listed under TV shows.

Thanks all.

Comment: Ah, yes: the Videos app is new in iOS 5.